# How to sum a column with $ and ',' '.' symbols? bash command line?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file, and I want to use something like "Cat" command on that file to prints out the sum of the column of the list.

The best I can do is

```
cat owe.txt  | awk '{sum+=$2 ; print $0} END{print "sum=",sum}'
```

But that doesn't work with the symbol '$' and ','

For example a column looks like This

```
Mike  $1.00
Mason $1,000,000.00
Tyler $100,000.00
Nick  $0.10
```

Result

```
sum=$1,100,001.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip the `$` and `,` for processing ... oh, and don't use `cat` if there's no need for it.

```
awk '{sum+=gensub(/[$,]/,"","g",$2) ; print $0} END{printf "sum=%8.2f\n",sum}' owe.txt
Mike  $1.00
Mason $1,000,000.00
Tyler $100,000.00
Nick  $0.10
sum= 1100001.10
```

The last part, getting the 1000 separators back in, I leave as an exercise to you, see the approach here:  [Printing thousand separated floats with GAWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751101/printing-thousand-separated-floats-with-gawk)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the excercise!

Comment: This doesn't work! awk: calling undefined function gensub

Comment: What os/which version of awk?

Comment: I'm on Mac Os. awk version 20070501

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/[$,]/,"",$2);sum+=$2 ; print $0} END{printf "sum=%8.2f\n",sum}' owe.txt`